# Custom UITableViewCell problem loading from NIB

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nib

UPDATE: **I've solved this now** - see my own comment. Amazing how often writing out the problem can lead to the resolution when you go through it again!

---

I must have read every thread on SO and the examples on Apple, but I just can't get this to work in my case and I wonder what I'm doing wrong?

I have made a custom cell in IB with XCode 4. The file's owner is set to the class of the custom view controller for the table and I have an IBOutlet for the UITableView cell which is hooked up OK from what I can tell. I  normally do all my table cells via code and use the fast scrolling method, but for this project I really need to use nibs to load the cell content and I'm having some grief I can't figure out.

So in my interface file I have;

```
@interface myCustomTableViewController <various delegates> {

   UITableViewCell *customNibCell;
   ...     
}

@property (nonatomic,assign) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *customNibCell;
```

In the customTableViewController I do this in my cellForRowAtIndexPath;

```
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@:"customDirCell"];

    if (cell == nil) {

        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DirectoryCellWithMenu" owner:self options: nil];

        cell = customNibCell;
        self.customNibCell = nil;

     }

     [self configureCell:cell atRow:indexPath.row];
```

And my configureCell method does this to reach into the cell and pull out the things I wish to customise.

```
UIImageView *fileImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
UILabel *headingTextLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:4];
UILabel *modifiedTextLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:5];
UILabel *sizeTextLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:6];
```

**The Problem**

The cells do load into the table OK in as much as I can see the correct layout. Furthermore, the custom actions I have defined on various buttons do all fire OK so it seems that the cell is hooked up properly.

BUT none of the customisation works - I can't seem to change the text of any of the labels for example and on investigation, **the result of every [cell viewWithTag:nn] is nil** which clearly signposts the problem, but I can't see what the cause is.

1. The identifier for the
   UITableViewCell is set to
   "customDirCell"
2. The object identities for the labels
   etc are indeed 3,4,5,6 according to
   IB
3. The xib contains exactly 1 object,
   the UITableViewCell

I can't see anything wrong with either the nib file creation or the code, but I'm obviously missing something!

Can any kind soul shed light on where I should be looking?

Comment: ARGGGH. OK, so I found the problem. I am confusing the Object ID identity (which is set by IB) with the Tag attribute - which is something I manually need to set. Hope this helps someone else who might fall into the same trap as I have!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this as per my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@:"customDirCell"];

    if (cell == nil) {

       NSArray *nib =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DirectoryCellWithMenu" owner:self options: nil];

        cell =[nib objectAtIndex:0];
        self.customNibCell = nil;

     }
```